# Posting to Twitter and Facebook using the SoundCloud API on Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, soundcloud

I'm having some trouble posting to Twitter and Facebook using the SoundCloud API when uploading an audio file. I have preexisting connections setup for Twitter and Facebook that I configured from the SoundCloud website. I have verified that they are both active by using a GET request on "/me/connections".

I'm not sure what parameter to use in order to post to Social Networks. I have tried "post_to", "shared_to", "shared-to", and "share_to". The API at http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading says to use "shared_to" but it isn't included in `com.soundcloud.api.Params` and I get an HTTP 422 unknown error when I manually enter the string. The iOS Sharing Guide at http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/ios-sharing uses "post_to" and that's included in `com.soundcloud.api.Params` but when I use that it posts the audio file to SoundCloud but doesn't post any messages to Twitter and Facebook. Here's the code I am using:

```
HttpResponse httpResp = Api.wrapper.get(Request.to(Endpoints.MY_CONNECTIONS));

JSONArray jsonCons = new JSONArray(Http.getString(httpResp));
String[] cons = new String[jsonCons.length()];
JSONObject jsonTemp;
for(int i = 0; i < jsonCons.length(); i++) {
    jsonTemp = jsonCons.getJSONObject(i);
    cons[i] = Integer.toString(jsonTemp.getInt("id"));;
}

httpResp = Api.wrapper.post(Request.to(Endpoints.TRACKS)
    .withFile(Params.Track.ASSET_DATA, file)
    .add(Params.Track.TITLE, file.getName())
    .add(Params.Track.SHARING, Params.Track.PUBLIC)
    .add(Params.Track.POST_TO, cons)
//  .add("track[shared_to][][id]", cons)
    .setProgressListener(new Request.TransferProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void transferred(long l) throws IOException {
            if (isCancelled()) throw new IOException("canceled");
            publishProgress(l, file.length());
        }
    }));
```

In the SoundCloud profile, I can also set it to post automatically on new uploaded sounds and it will post to Twitter and Facebook as long as I don't include the param for "post_to" but I want to be able to control what and when I post. I would appreciate any help that you could provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify:

- `shared_to` is for sharing to specific user ids / emails
- `post_to` is for social networks

the `add(String, Object)` method on the wrapper unfortunately doesn't accept arrays/collections, so you have to add them like this:

```
httpResp = Api.wrapper.post(Request.to(Endpoints.TRACKS)
  .add("track[shared_to][emails][][address]", "foo@example.com")
  .add("track[shared_to][emails][][address]", "baz@example.com")
  .add("track[shared_to][users][][id]",       "1")
  .add("track[shared_to][users][][id]",       "2")
  .add("track[post_to][][id]",                "3")
  .add("track[post_to][][id]",                "4")
```

I've fixed the wrapper ([1](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/commit/5e830db9ebcb03869b3ad146197738f100e84e09)), the next release will support collections/arrays in the "add" call, in the meantime you can use the [snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/1.3.1-SNAPSHOT/) version.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. That fixed it for me but definitely was not clear in the SoundCloud API documentation. It says to use "shared_to" in the "Sharing Sounds to other Social Networks" section and doesn't list "post_to" in the documentation at all.